# Spivak's Calculus 22-28 on infinite sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following question is extracted from Spivak's Calculus 22-28:

[image]

For part (a) I have:

Choose $N$ such that for $n,m>N$ we have $|x_n-x_m|<\delta$.  Then, since $f$ is uniformly continuous and $x_n, x_m$ are rational, it follows that $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|<\epsilon$.  Hence the sequence ${f(x_n)}$ is a cauchy sequence and convergent.

However I'm not sure it is correct as the answers book has a different long winded answer.

Also can anyone give a solution to part (b)?

Comment: In your solution to part a you should not that the reason you can find such an N is that the sequence converging to x is Cauchy .

Comment: Note that the uniform continuity of $f$ on  the rationals is necessary. If $f(x)=0$ for $x\in \Bbb Q\cap [0,1/\sqrt 2\;)$  and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in \Bbb Q \cap (1/\sqrt 2\;,1] $ then $f$  is continuous on $[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$  but $f$ cannot be extended to a continuous  $\bar f: [0,1]\to \Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the range of the function $f$ is contained in $\Bbb R$.

Your proof of (a) is correct.

To prove (b) consider an arbitrary sequence $\{x’_n\}$ of rational numbers, converging to the point $x$. Then the sequence $x_1,x’_1,x_2,x’_2,\dots $ is Cauchy, so the sequence $f(x_1), f(x’_1), f(x_2), f(x’_2), \dots$ is Cauchy too, thus it converges to the same limit $\bar f(x)$ of its subsequence  $\{f(x_n)\}$. So its subsequence $\{f(x’_n)\}$ aslo converges to $\bar f(x)$.

Proof of (c). Let $x,y$ be any real numbers from the interval such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Put $\delta’=\frac 12(\delta -|x-y|)$. Let   $\{x_n\}$ (resp., $\{y_n\}$) be an arbitrary sequence of rational numbers, converging to the point $x$ (resp., $y$).  Choose $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have

$$|x_n−x|<\delta’\mbox{, }|y_n−y|<\delta'\mbox{, }|f(x_n)-\bar f(x)|<\varepsilon\mbox{, and }|f(y_n)-\bar f(y)|<\varepsilon.$$ Pick any $n>N$. Then

$$|x_n-y_n|=|x_n-x+x-y+y-y_n|\le$$ $$ |x_n-x|+|x-y|+|y-y_n|<$$ $$\delta’+|x-y|+\delta’=\delta.$$

Thus $$|\bar f(x)-\bar f(y)|=$$ $$ |\bar f(x)- f(x_n)+f(x_n)-f(y_n)+f(y_n)-\bar f(y)|\le$$ 
$$|\bar f(x)- f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|+|f(y_n)-\bar f(y)|<$$ $$\varepsilon+\varepsilon+\varepsilon=3\varepsilon.$$

PS. A similar claim holds for metric spaces, see the following theorem from Ryszard Engelking's "General topology"

[image]

Comment: What do you mean (resp.,$\{y_n\}$?)

Comment: @helios321 The sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to the point $x$ and the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to the point $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as you used in a) : If $x_n$ and $y_n$ both converge to $x$   then  their difference $x_n-y_n$ converges to $0$ so again given $\epsilon >0$ there is $N$ such that  |$x_n-y_n| < \delta$ if $n,m >N$ . Then  $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| < \epsilon$ . If the sequences converge to $A$ and $B$ then taking limits  gives $|A-B|\leq \epsilon .$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $A=B$.

Comment: My edit was "cosmetic". The math is fine. BTW it's easier & usually looks better to put dollar-signs  only at the beginning and end of an entire  formula.